# Two joins with different clauses to same table in Entity Framework lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to convert a SQL query to a lambda expression.

SQL query looks like this:

```
select 
    po.OrderID as order_number,
    pc.emailaddress as user_email,
    pc.CustomerID as customer_code,
    pb.DisplayName as bank,
    poab.street1 + ' ' + poab.Street2 as 'billing_address',
    po.createdate as 'created_date',
    'tr' as currency,
    po.TotalPrice - po.TotalPromotionPrice as discount_amount,
    null as 'extra_field',
    pbi.InstalmentCount as installment_count,
    pp.DisplayName as payment_type,
    poas.street1 + ' ' + poas.street2 as 'shipping_address',
    'UPS' as shipping_company,
    pos.Displayname as status,
    po.ShipmentReferenceNo as 'tracking_number'
from
    PrmOrder po
inner join 
    prmcustomer pc on po.CustomerID = pc.customerid
inner join 
    PrmBank pb on po.BankId = pb.BankId
inner join 
    prmorderaddress poab on po.orderid = poab.orderid and poab.isbillingaddress = 1
left join 
    PrmBankInstalment pbi on pbi.BankInstalmentID = po.BankInstalmentID
inner join 
    PrmPaymentType pp on po.PaymentTypeID = pp.PaymentTypeId
inner join 
    prmorderaddress poas on po.orderid = poas.orderid and poas.isshippingaddress = 1
inner join 
    prmorderstatus pos on po.orderstatusid = pos.orderstatusid
```

I inner joined same table twice because of one-to-many connections between these two tables and my need to show both lines. Basically, an OrderID can have two records on OrderAddress table, one for billing address and other for shipping address. It worked well on SQL but I couldn't translate it into a lambda expression.

I tried something like this first;

```
var OrderHeader = db.PrmOrders
                .Include(x => x.PrmCustomer)
                .Include(x => x.PrmBank)
                .Include(x => x.PrmOrderAddresses)
                .Include(x => x.PrmBankInstalment)
                .Include(x => x.PrmPaymentType)
                .Include(x => x.PrmOrderStatu)
                .Where(x => x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress != null && x.OrderStatusID != 1 && x.OrderID > OrderID)
                .OrderBy(x => x.OrderID)
.Select(x => new HeaderDTO()
             {
                 order_number = x.OrderID,
                 user_email = x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress,
                 customer_code = x.PrmCustomer.CustomerID,
                 order_amount = x.GrandTotal,
                 bank = x.PrmBank.DisplayName,
                 billing_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
                                     .Where(c => c.IsBillingAddress == true && c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
                                     .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2).ToString(),
                 created_date = x.OrderDate,
                 currency = "TRY",
                 discount_amount = x.TotalPrice - x.TotalPromotionPrice,
                 installment_count = x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount == null ? 0 : x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount,
                 payment_type = x.PrmPaymentType.DisplayName,
                 shipping_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
                                     .Where(c => c.IsShippingAddress == true & c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
                                     .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2 + " " + c.PrmAddressCity.DisplayName + " " + c.PrmAddressCountry.DisplayName).ToString(),
                 shipping_company = "UPS",
                 status = x.PrmOrderStatu.DisplayName,
                 tracking_number = x.ShipmentReferenceNo == null ? "" : x.ShipmentReferenceNo
             });
```

This caused V`alues of type 'collection[Edm.String(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=,Unicode=,FixedLength=)]' can not be converted to string.` error and deleting / re-adding table in the Edmx didn't work, as it was suggested.

So now I'm trying a triple join with Lambda expressions and it doesn't feel quite right and looks a bit confusing

```
var OrderHeader = db.PrmOrders
                .Include(x => x.PrmCustomer)
                .Include(x => x.PrmBank)
                .Include(x => x.PrmOrderAddresses)
                .Include(x => x.PrmBankInstalment)
                .Include(x => x.PrmPaymentType)
                .Include(x => x.PrmOrderStatu)
                .Where(x => x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress != null && x.OrderStatusID != 1 && x.OrderID > OrderID)
                .OrderBy(x => x.OrderID)
                .Join(db.PrmOrderAddresses.Where(a => a.IsBillingAddress == true), x => x.OrderID, a => a.OrderID, (x, a) => new
                {
                    BillingAddress = a.Street1 + " " + a.Street2 + " " + a.PrmAddressCity.DisplayName + " " + a.PrmAddressCountry.DisplayName,
                    OrderID = x.OrderID
                })
                .Join(db.PrmOrderAddresses.Where(a => a.IsShippingAddress == true), x => x.OrderID, s => s.OrderID, (x, s) => new
                {
                    order_number = x.OrderID,
                    user_email = x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress,
                    customer_code = x.PrmCustomer.CustomerID,
                    order_amount = x.GrandTotal,
                    bank = x.PrmBank.DisplayName,
                    //billing_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
                    //                    .Where(c => c.IsBillingAddress == true && c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
                    //                    .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2).ToString(),
                    created_date = x.OrderDate,
                    currency = "TRY",
                    discount_amount = x.TotalPrice - x.TotalPromotionPrice,
                    installment_count = x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount == null ? 0 : x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount,
                    payment_type = x.PrmPaymentType.DisplayName,
                    //shipping_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
                    //                    .Where(c => c.IsShippingAddress == true & c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
                    //                    .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2 + " " + c.PrmAddressCity.DisplayName + " " + c.PrmAddressCountry.DisplayName).ToString(),
                    shipping_company = "UPS",
                    status = x.PrmOrderStatu.DisplayName,
                    tracking_number = x.ShipmentReferenceNo == null ? "" : x.ShipmentReferenceNo
                    ShippingAddress = s.Street1 + " " + s.Street2 + " " + s.PrmAddressCity.DisplayName + " " + s.PrmAddressCountry.DisplayName
                });
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: As an FYI: `Include` is ignored the moment you use `Select`, so all those statements are useless

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you cannot convert an Expression into a string, it doesn't make any sense.
You have to decide between using a `ToList`/`ToArray` if there are many items,  `First` if there is always one item or `FirstOrDefault` if there could be none:

```
var OrderHeader = db.PrmOrders
    .Where(x => x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress != null && x.OrderStatusID != 1 && x.OrderID > OrderID)
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrderID)
    .Select(x => new HeaderDTO
     {
         order_number = x.OrderID,
         user_email = x.PrmCustomer.EmailAddress,
         customer_code = x.PrmCustomer.CustomerID,
         order_amount = x.GrandTotal,
         bank = x.PrmBank.DisplayName,
         billing_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
             .Where(c => c.IsBillingAddress && c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
             .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2)
             .ToList() / .First() / .FirstOrDefault(),
         created_date = x.OrderDate,
         currency = "TRY",
         discount_amount = x.TotalPrice - x.TotalPromotionPrice,
         installment_count = x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount == null ? 0 : x.PrmBankInstalment.InstalmentCount,
         payment_type = x.PrmPaymentType.DisplayName,
         shipping_address = x.PrmOrderAddresses
             .Where(c => c.IsShippingAddress && c.OrderID == x.OrderID)
             .Select(c => c.Street1 + " " + c.Street2 + " " + c.PrmAddressCity.DisplayName + " " + c.PrmAddressCountry.DisplayName)
             .ToList() / .First() / .FirstOrDefault(),
         shipping_company = "UPS",
         status = x.PrmOrderStatu.DisplayName,
         tracking_number = x.ShipmentReferenceNo == null ? "" : x.ShipmentReferenceNo
     });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. But I'm afraid now the title of question is a bit misleading for future searchers.